# highlight blank rows

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to highlight all the blank rows in a range ?

I have tried conditional formatting with formula, find and select option.. but the problem is i get blank cells highlighted. but i need the complete blank row highlighted.

Comment: yes, you can do it with conditional formating, google 's your friend.

Comment: This question is down to a bare minimum. Please check [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordinly.

Comment: Yes there is a fair number of ways. Can you let us know what you have tried so far and where you have gotten stuck with this? Not showing any attempt or effort will most likely get you [downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: @JvdV I have made my edits. I hope now it looks better and as per compliance.

Comment: @Plutian thanks for the comment. I have made the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with conditional formatting.

Click "Conditional Formatting" and "New Rule". Then select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Set which colour you would like to format your cells and enter this formula:

```
=COUNTA(1:1)=0
```

This will test all rows if they have any values in them at all. If not, `Counta(` will return 0, and this formula returns true meaning the row will be highlighted.

Apply this to column `=$A:$AB` (or change the last value to where the end of your data is)

Answer (score 0):

The range B5:F5 is formatted with a conditional formatting rule based on this 
  formula:

```
 =COUNTBLANK($B5:$F5)
```

conditional formatting formulas be entered relative to the "first cell" in the selection, B5 in this case.

Comment: hi ,  i need complete row to be highlighted as mentioned.